# Ошибка import - просьба пояснить причину: from vkbottle import Bot, Message ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'vkbottle'

Tags: python, вконтакте

```
from vkbottle import Bot, Message
from vkbottle.api.keyboard import Keyboard, Text
from vkbottle.branch import Branch, ExitBranch


bot=Bot('')

dialogs = {}
wait = []
emoji = '' # Спасибо моему IDLE :)

start_keyboard = Keyboard(one_time=False)
start_keyboard.add_row()
start_keyboard.add_button(Text(label="Поиск собеседника"), color="negative")

wait_keyboard = Keyboard(one_time=True)
wait_keyboard.add_row()
wait_keyboard.add_button(Text(label="Отменить поиск"), color="positive")

stop_keyboard = Keyboard(one_time=False)
stop_keyboard.add_row()
stop_keyboard.add_button(Text(label="Отключиться от диалога"), color="primary")


@bot.on.message(text='Поиск собеседника', lower = True)
async def start(ans: Message):
    if ans.from_id not in wait and ans.from_id not in dialogs:
        if len(wait) == 0:
            await ans(f'{emoji} Вы добавлены в очередь поиска собеседника.', keyboard=wait_keyboard)
            wait.append(ans.from_id)
            await bot.branch.add(ans.peer_id, "wait")
        else:
            dialogs[ans.from_id] = wait[0]
            dialogs[wait[0]] = ans.from_id
            await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=ans.from_id, random_id=0, message=f'{emoji} Мы нашли вам собеседника!', keyboard=stop_keyboard)
            await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=wait[0], random_id=0, message=f'{emoji} Мы нашли вам собеседника!', keyboard=stop_keyboard)
            await bot.branch.add(ans.from_id, "dialog")
            await bot.branch.add(wait[0], "dialog")
            del wait[0]

@bot.branch.simple_branch("wait")
async def branch(ans: Message):
    if ans.text == "Отменить поиск":
        await ans(f"{emoji} Поиск собеседника остановлен.", keyboard=start_keyboard)
        await bot.branch.exit(ans.peer_id)
        del wait[0]
    else:
        await ans(f'{emoji} Вы находитесь в поиске собеседника.', keyboard=wait_keyboard)

@bot.branch.simple_branch("dialog")
async def branch(ans: Message):
    if ans.text == "Отключиться от диалога":
        await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=ans.from_id, random_id=0, message=f'{emoji} Диалог был остановлен.', keyboard=start_keyboard)
        await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=dialogs[ans.from_id], random_id=0, message=f'{emoji} Собеседник остановил диалог.', keyboard=start_keyboard)
        await bot.branch.exit(dialogs[ans.from_id])
        await bot.branch.exit(ans.from_id)
        del dialogs[dialogs[ans.from_id]]
        del dialogs[ans.from_id]
    else:
        await bot.api.messages.send(peer_id=dialogs[ans.from_id], random_id=0, message='Собеседник: ' + ans.text)

@bot.on.message()
async def all(ans: Message):
    await ans('Привет! Я анонимный чат-бот. Чтобы начать поиск собеседника, воспользуйтесь кнопками.', keyboard=start_keyboard)

bot.run_polling()
```

Comment: Пишите более ясно вопросы, пожалуйста (отредактировал заголовок). И где вы в документации vkbottle увидели Message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
from vkbottle import Bot, Message
```

используйте

```
from vkbottle import Bot
from vkbottle.bot import Message
```

т.к. в модуле `vkbottle` не существует класс `Message`

Comment: Отлично спасибо помогло)

Comment: Не стоит. :-) [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто импортировать всю библиотеку: `import vkbottle`, думаю поможет

Comment: у вас получилось?

Comment: NameError: name 'Bot' is not defined новая ошибка

Comment: а если вы просто не будете импортировать message, то ничего работать не будет? Не особо разбираюсь в vbottle. Ещё попробуйте написать: ```from vkbottle import *```